# Spring Integration Java DSL: How to route with the channelMapping method to the channel which name is in the headers?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to route with the `channelMapping` method to the channel which name is in the headers? So if I try this

```
    @Bean
    private IntegrationFlow postDataToChannelX() {
            return f -> f
            ...
               .<String, Boolean> route(s -> s.equals("[]"), m -> m
                    .channelMapping(false, "headers['channelName']")
                    .channleMapping(true, ...);
    }
```

there comes

> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'headers['channelName']' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'headers['channelName']' available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do like this:

```
.route(Message.class, (m) -> m.getHeaders().get("channelName"))
```

So, you don't need any mapping at all since you resolve to the target channel directly in the routing function.

Comment: Edited the question. There was the route before the `channelMapping`, so I think I need the `channelMapping`. So how to route with the channelMapping method to the channel which name is in the headers?

Comment: Ok. You can include that into the routing function as well. I mean you do ternary operator and return the channel you need. The mapping is only for static channels

Comment: Thanks for the answer